# Guidance on use of DUnitX in Delphi

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, mocking

For too many years I have been writing tightly-coupled spaghetti Delphi code.
I have decided to stop doing this and write only clean testable code from now on.
So, I have been studying clean code, dependency injection, refactoring, decoupling, unit testing, etc, etc (Nick Hodges, Ray Konopka, Uncle Bob, Alister Christie to name a few).

I'm stuck on how to go about unit testing one of my classes (using DUnitX). All the examples I have researched so far show the CUT's dependency interface being mocked and then being injected in the CUT's constructor, like this (from Nick Hodges):

```
procedure TestTCCValidator.TestCardChargeReturnsProperAmountWhenCardIsGood;
var
  CCManager: TCreditCardManager;
  CCValidator: TMock<ICreditCardValidator>;
  GoodCard: String;
  Input: Double;
  Expected, Actual: Double;
begin
  //Arrange
  GoodCard := '123456';
  Input := 49.95;
  Expected := Input;
  CCValidator := TMock<ICreditCardValidator>.Create;
  CCValidator.Setup.WillReturn(True).When.IsCreditCardValid(GoodCard);
  CCManager := TCreditCardManager.Create(CCValidator);
  try
  //Act
  Actual := CCManager.ProcessCreditCard(GoodCard, Input)
  finally
  CCManager.Free;
  end;
  // Assert
Assert.AreEqual(Expected, Actual);
end;
```

That's fine and I understand all of it.

Unfortunately, my class does not have a constructor. It's only dependency (which is a record, not an interface) is passed in a class procedure, as follows:

This unit contains the interface implemented by my class...

```
unit Unit15;

interface

type
  TMyRecord = record
    Flag: boolean
  end;

  IMyInterface = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{17783F54-0F63-413B-8198-88705CBA318F}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;


implementation

end.
```

This unit contains my class (that implements the above interface)...

```
unit Unit14;

interface

uses
  Unit15;

type
  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
    FRec: TMyRecord;
    procedure DoSomething;
    procedure DoThis;
    procedure DoThat;
    class procedure Execute(ARec: TMyRecord);
  end;

implementation

{ MyClass }

procedure TMyClass.DoSomething;
begin
  case FRec.Flag of
    true: DoThis;
    false: DoThat;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoThat;
begin
  writeln('did that');
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoThis;
begin
  writeln('did this');
end;

class procedure TMyClass.Execute(ARec: TMyRecord);
begin
  var mc: IMyInterface := TMyClass.Create;
  TMyClass(mc).FRec := ARec;
  mc.DoSomething;
end;

end.
```

And here is how you might deploy my class...

```
program Project12;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit14 in 'Unit14.pas',
  Unit15 in 'Unit15.pas';

var
  Rec: TMyRecord;

begin
  try
    Rec.Flag := true;
    TMyClass.Execute(Rec);
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I created a DUnitX project and started to proceed like Nick's credit card manager example. But this is where I think I have failed to fully grasp the techniques used in unit testing. My Test project has this unit...

```
unit Unit16;

interface

uses
  Unit14,
  Unit15,
  DUnitX.TestFramework;

type
  [TestFixture]
  TMyTestObject = class
  private
    FRec: TMyRecord;
    CUT: TMyClass;     // do I need this?
  public
    [Setup]
    procedure Setup;
    [TearDown]
    procedure TearDown;
    [Test]
//    [TestCase('Text Execute with true flag', true)]   // causes compiler error
//    [TestCase('Text Execute with false flag', false)]  // causes compiler error
    procedure TestExecute(const AFlag: boolean);
  end;

  // how do I mock IMyInterface (which is created in TMyClass.Execute)?

implementation

procedure TMyTestObject.Setup;
begin
end;

procedure TMyTestObject.TearDown;
begin
end;

procedure TMyTestObject.TestExecute(const AFlag: boolean);
begin
  FRec.Flag := AFlag;
  TMyClass.Execute(FRec);
end;

initialization
  TDUnitX.RegisterTestFixture(TMyTestObject);

end.
```

How should I test that DoSomething behaves correctly when called?

Is it possible to test MyClass as I have written it or must I restructure it?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You can only test methods and functionality that has some side-effects (state changes) accessible to the outside world and test framework. If you cannot observe the effects of the method you want to test, then you cannot test it.

In this particular case ability to test would mean reading the console output buffer and checking whether you got the expected output written. As far as I know there is a Windows API that allows you to do this, but I cannot say how easy or hard would be to implement test using that API. Obviously, writing to console is used just as example in your code, but it shows the principle.

That console is actually a hard coded dependency you shouldn't have in testable code. It is a dependency that makes it hard to check and verify for correctness and such dependencies should be avoided as much as possible, even if you have some means to verify the side-effects.

In your case that would mean introducing `TConsoleWriter` as dependency for `TMyClass`. That dependency would be then passed as a parameter of injected through dependency injection. Once you have that, then you can replace that dependency with  some test double (mock) and you can observe the side-effects that happen when you run your test and verify whether you got the expected results.

If the side-effects of your code are not related to outside dependency, but are encapsulated within the class itself, then you need to allow access (read-only will suffice) to encapsulated data that allows you to verify the results of a method call.

Comment: Dalija, thank you for your response. 

Yes, writing to the console was just for the sake of my example - to show that DoThis and DoThat do actually have a purpose. 

Perhaps I over simplified my example. 

The side effects of DoThis and DoThat in my real project are significant (write to the clipboard or to a file) so it looks like I still have some work to do to make it properly testable.

I'm still learning!

Comment: What you need to check is whether content sent to clipboard and content sent to file is the one you expect it to be. When you have file output, then commonly you would have method that writes to stream and then you would test that method and then you would merely pass filestream when you need to write it to file. You can even test code that writes to the file directly (although this is technically integration test) and verify whether file exists and its content.

Comment: Clipboard can be harder to test, but again you can separate the part that prepares the data and the code that actually sends the data to clipboard. Testing data in clipboard again falls into integration tests. Even if you find some parts of your code is harder to test, you should minimize amount of code that you cannot test. If you have method that uses something it is hard to test, then extract anything you can test out of that method.

Comment: OK, thanks. I need to figure out how to test TMyClass.DoSomething (implementation of IMyInterface.DoSomething) in Unit14. I want to know if it makes the right choice (DoThis or DoThat). I have studied quite a few examples and they all assume the CUT has a constructor which takes a Mocked interface as a parameter. MyClass is not like that - must I change it so that it is?

Comment: Either you need a constructor or you need to inject the dependency through some DI framework. Testing will require changes in your code if the code is not testable as-is.